# How do I show that a topological space is discrete if all its subsets are closed?

Tags: general-topology

I was doing problems from Topology Without Tears and found this question.

I have a topological space $(X,\tau)$ such that all its subsets are closed. I need to show that $(X,\tau)$ is a discrete space.

I know that all the subsets of $X$ are clopen and subset $\phi$ is also clopen. Can this fact be used to prove the same?

Comment: If all subsets are closed, then their complements, i.e., again all subsets, are open.

Comment: So, that implies that all the subsets of $X$ belong to $\tau$ and so we are done? Am I right?

Comment: Doesn't it say every *infinite* subset is closed?

Comment: How you prove it depends a lot on **how discrete topology is defined**. One possible definition would be "all subsets are closed". I guess that's not the one you're using.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The OP says he already knows that "all the subsets of $X$ are clopen". So, unless he has a very unusual definition of "clopen", it seems that he already knows that all subsets are open.

Comment: You know that ***all*** the subsets of $X$ are clopen, and you know that the subset $\phi$ is ***also*** clopen. But what about the subset $X$ itself? Do you know that $X$ is clopen?

Comment: Don't all the closed subsets of X belong to $\tau$ ? So that means their complements, open sets are subsets of X, so all the subsets now belong to $\tau$ hence completing the proof. Is this okay?

Answer (score 0):

Let { Uα : αϵI } be collection of all subsets of set X.
since all subsets of X are closed 
⇒  compliments of all subsets are open 
⇒  compliments of all subsets are in τ i.e U'α ϵ τ for each  α
⇒  all subsets of x are in τ  i.e Uα ϵ τ , so (X,τ ) is discrete topological space